# Distraction Free Mode and dual screen

Tags: configuration, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How can I configure Sublime such that the distraction free mode disables a second monitor? This option does not seem to be in the default configration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a new sublime window in distraction free mode on your second monitor.

Answer (score -2):

Its really quick, simply switch off the second monitor might be the easiest solution.
I understand this might not be the solution you seek but this is how i do it. :)

Comment: Except if you have a crappy monitor which takes literally 3 seconds to turn on...

Comment: Sorry my friend there is nothing that i can do about it :)